# qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

After running the code below I get the following error:

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import sys
import time
 
import requests
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, QTimer, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow,  QPlainTextEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,
    )
 
from bluepy import btle
 
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    signalMsg = pyqtSignal(str)
    signalRes = pyqtSignal(str)
    
class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    
    def __init__(self, sgn):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.sgn = sgn
 
    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        
        try:
            dataDecoded = data.decode()
            self.sgn.signalRes.emit(dataDecoded)
        except UnicodeError:
            print("UnicodeError: ", data)
 
class WorkerBLE(QRunnable):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.rqsToSend = False
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.signals.signalMsg.emit("WorkerBLE start")
        
        #---------------------------------------------
        p = btle.Peripheral("3c:71:bf:0d:dd:6a")
        p.setDelegate( MyDelegate(self.signals) )
 
        svc = p.getServiceByUUID("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
        self.ch_Tx = svc.getCharacteristics("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")[0]
        ch_Rx = svc.getCharacteristics("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")[0]
 
        setup_data = b"\x01\00"
        p.writeCharacteristic(ch_Rx.valHandle+1, setup_data)
 
        # BLE loop --------
 
        while True:
            """
            if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
                # handleNotification() was called
                continue
 
            print("Waiting...")
            """
            
            p.waitForNotifications(1.0)
            
            if self.rqsToSend:
                self.rqsToSend = False
 
                try:
                    self.ch_Tx.write(self.bytestosend, True)
                except btle.BTLEException:
                    print("btle.BTLEException");
            
        #---------------------------------------------hellohello
        self.signals.signalMsg.emit("WorkerBLE end")
        
    def toSendBLE(self, tosend):
        self.bytestosend = bytes(tosend, 'utf-8')
        self.rqsToSend = True
        """
        try:
            self.ch_Tx.write(bytestosend, True)
        except BTLEException:
            print("BTLEException");
        """
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        buttonStartBLE = QPushButton("Start BLE")
        buttonStartBLE.pressed.connect(self.startBLE)
        
        self.console = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.console.setReadOnly(True)
        
        self.outconsole = QPlainTextEdit()
        
        buttonSendBLE = QPushButton("Send message")
        buttonSendBLE.pressed.connect(self.sendBLE)
 
        layout.addWidget(buttonStartBLE)
        layout.addWidget(self.console)
        layout.addWidget(self.outconsole)
        layout.addWidget(buttonSendBLE)
        
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        
        self.show()
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print(
            "Multithreading with Maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())
            
    def startBLE(self):
        self.workerBLE = WorkerBLE()
        self.workerBLE.signals.signalMsg.connect(self.slotMsg)
        self.workerBLE.signals.signalRes.connect(self.slotRes)
        self.threadpool.start(self.workerBLE)
        
    def sendBLE(self):
        strToSend = self.outconsole.toPlainText()
        self.workerBLE.toSendBLE(strToSend)
        
    def slotMsg(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        
    def slotRes(self, res):
        self.console.appendPlainText(res)
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Comment: See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified).

Answer (score 9):

If you are running this application from `ssh` session make sure to set environment variable `display` by running `export DISPLAY=:0.0 # Or any other port` and display is connected

Comment: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Multithreading with Maximum 4 threads
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 191, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20

Comment: now I get the above...

Answer (score 4):

If you are running this on a machine that has no display/graphical output, make sure that your script does not call any cv2 functions for graphical output like `cv2.namedWindow` or `cv2.imshow`.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen ./yourAppExe
```

Comment: I got the following error when setting the env var **QT_QPA_PLATFORM**.  Any idea why?

`qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "offscreen" in "/somepath/miniconda3/envs/some_env_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.`

Comment: @user3731622, You can run your application with the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environment variable set to 1 to see what might go wrong when the plugin is loaded.